# Safari content blockers turn off

Tags: javascript, safari, phishing

I have link and in Safari i show popup "Phishing warning "

How to turn content blocking on and off
On your Mac, you can turn content blocking on and off in AdBlock's options, on the "GENERAL" tab.
On your iPhone or iPad, it's in Settings > Safari > Content Blockers.
https://help.getadblock.com/support/solutions/articles/6000099239-what-is-safari-content-blocking-

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201265

How Turn off Anti-phishing and Content Blockers with Javascript ?

Comment: You don't, and you shouldn't. At least, if your question is to turn users blockers off with Javascript.

Comment: maybee change URL ?